# Can you change the name of a network drive?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mount, smb

I have a couple of network shares which all have the same name on different servers and I'd like to change the label of the mounted disk to tell me which server its on.

Can mounted network drives be renamed on mac os?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mount the share using terminal you can assign the mount point
to a local directory. Source: Macworld Mac OS X Hints: [*Ten different ways to connect to servers*](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100403050702737)

> create a directory -- the mountpoint -- where the contents of the
>   mounted server will appear.

```
$ mkdir /mnt/music
$ mkdir /mnt/movie
```

> The mount command should be more or less familar:

```
mount_smbfs //admin:stevie123@macmediaserver.local/itunesmusic /mnt/music ## for SMB shares ##
mount_afp afp://admin:stevie123@macmediaserver.local/mymovies /mnt/movie ## for AFP shares ##
```

The [*man* pages for *mount*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html) provide complete documentation.

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't change mount point names.